# Variable problem when using FB.api async calls with jQuery.when()

Tags: facebook, javascript

Trying to get data from several calls to FB into one array and operate with it when ready. Unfortunately. Script waits for response, but in any way I cannot access it later.

```
    var xxx = 0; // Counter to check
    var friendsRequest = []; // Array to catch all calls and execute the code when all responses are back
    var friends = ['...','...']; // array of friend id's

    for (var i = 0; i < friends.length; i++) {
        var friend = friends[i]; // Go through number of FB friends (doesn't matter)

        // Here we save all calls to wait for result
        friendsRequest[friend] = FB.api('/' + friend + '/picture?redirect=0&height=64&type=square&width=64', function(response) {
            xxx++; // Try to increment the counter
            console.log(xxx); // Works fine.
        });
    }

    // Execute the code when all data collected.
    // It executes correctly __after__ last FB.api() async call ends
    $.when(friendsRequest).then(function(){
        console.log(xxx); // But here we have always "0"
    });
```

Maybe $.when somehow does not work with several FB.api() calls? Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: This looks a programming question and probably belongs on [so].

Comment: Oops. You are correct, is there a way to move it there?

Comment: Yes, copy the markdown code of this question to a new one in SO, then delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple mistakes here:

**1)** Arrays should not be iterated like this:

```
for(i in ['...','...'])
```

When you do that, `i` will be the index into the array, not the item in the array.  And, it will be iterating through properties of the object which can sometime be more than just array elements.  You should iterate array elements with either:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    // process array[i]
}
```

or with `.forEach()`:

```
array.forEach(function(item, index) {
    // process item here
});
```

**2)** I don't know the FB api myself, but I don't see any documentation that `FB.api()` returns a promise.  `$.when()` only works with promises.

**3)** When you are accumulating items in `friendsRequest`, you are building an object, not an array.  Assuming `friend.id` is a string, `friendsRequest[friend.id]` sets the property of an object, not an array element.

**4)** If you want to use an actual array with `$.when()` (after you fixed other things to actually have an array), `$.when()` expects to be called like this:

```
$.when(p1, p2, p3, p4)
```

where p1 ... p4 are promises.  So, if you have an array of promises, then you can call `$.when()` in the appropriate way by doing this:

```
$.when.apply($, arrayOfPromises)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Regarding the 1). the code was not working, just to show the logic.

It seems the answer I was looking for was Nr. 2. Do you have any idea how to execute the code after a group of requests to services like FB?

Comment: @IljaPolivanovas - There are numerous choices: 1) You can keep a count of how many async requests are pending and when the count gets to zero, you know all are done and you can execute your code, 2) You can make your own wrapper function that calls `FB.api()` and returns a promise that is resolved when the callback is done and 3) You can use a promise library (like Bluebird) that has a `.promisify()` method that will create the wrapper for you.  With 2) or 3), you can then use `$.when()` with multiple promises to tell you when then are all done.